# Will adopting a DVCS mean there will be a positive impact on development speed?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, perforce

I was wondering how safe is to say that —because developers are free to version and have better and more organic workflows— code will be delivered faster.

A big factor here is team size of course, and I'd say the team is big enough to see this benefit (10-15 core devs, and maybe 5 to 15 more contributors to the common codebase).

**Edit**: How development speed can be affected:

- [Merging hell](http://accurev.com/blog/2012/03/07/avoiding-merge-hell/) could be one of the cases that slow down people (DVCSs are much better at merging).
- Better workflows that <strike>can pretty much only work</strike> work more naturally on a DVCS

  **Integration Manager**

  [image: Integration Manager]

  **Dictator & Lieutenants**

  [image]
- Ability to use version control (i.e. committing) without inflicting potentially unstable changes to everybody

I just want to know if anyone has seen such things help the overall speed of teams/projects as a whole.

Comment: Why would code be delivered slower if you stayed with the CVCS?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen See edit

Comment: Have you researched if any of these "could slow downs" actually do?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen ...actually yes. Resolving difficult merges (which otherwise are better handled by DVCS's thanks to more robust version metadata) can take days because people don't want to merge and then someone has to, merging occurs way more often in DVCSs. Better workflows such as the ones presented shield non-interested parties from instability where they don't care for certain changes until they are stable (see Dictator & Lieutenants). Ability to use version control alone helps you refine your work faster.

Comment: So the company in question actually _have_ difficult merges?  Then I would focus on that, with an actual use case where you explicitly compare the two.

Comment: @dukeofgaming: "merging occurs way more often in DVCSs". No, merging occurs when the developers want to do it. Devs who don't merge often won't suddenly start merging - the problem is still a workflow/team one.

Comment: `Better workflows that can pretty much only work on a DVCS and otherwise be difficult on CVCSs` I highly doubt that. At work, we use ClearCase and I set up a workflow very similar to the [Separate features workflow](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/#separate_features) often used with Mercurial. I've also been able to employ Mercurial's [Sharing Changes](http://mercurial.selenic.com/guide/#sharing_changes) workflow. I can see how you can fairly easily implement these in Subversion, as well. So I don't consider this a valid point of comparison between distributed and centralized versioning.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Granted, didn't mean to assert an absolute, I know they could just email their patches until the last line of defense before the repository and it could be regarded as the same workflow. Should've written: `work more naturally under a DVCS`

Comment: @ThomasOwens I haven't been at an organization that hasn't needed a team of people just to deal with ClearCase, where SCM's like Mercurial and Git seem to just work. I'm not saying ClearCase is broken, I'm saying ClearCase seems to make organizations want to develop the most convoluted, hard to use, complex workflows, that if a single SCM guy is sick for a day, no work gets checked in. So a simple switch from ClearCase to Git can remove blocks (i.e. People) from the equation thus increasing productivity.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell I've seen that as well, and I wouldn't suggest that any organization use ClearCase because of the cost and technological resources needed to make it work. However, even as technologically different as ClearCase is to Git and Mercurial, I managed to set up very similar workflows for software development that address the same concerns without a significant amount of convolution (well, no more than usual when dealing with ClearCase). I suspect I could also make those workflows work just as well with Subversion (although I've never tried).

Comment: Your choice of naming for "Dictator" vs "Integration Manager" is kind of biasing the question here IMO.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson It's not mine, it is a common analogy for that structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In our line of work, it's sometimes difficult to see the human element.  I believe DVCS has the *potential* to speed up a workflow, but a large number of developers are either unable or unwilling to learn it well enough to use it to its full potential.

In my experience, around 1 in 10 developers already get it, another 2 in 10 would learn and use it to potential after the company switched, and when you explain the benefits of DVCS to the other 70%, they respond something like, "Why would anyone ever want to do that?"  If forced to use it, they will make the experience as close to their familiar CVCS workflow as possible, thereby negating most of the benefits.

Comment: Good point, this is how a DVCS could slow things down. I plan to start a pilot test, and then try to expand it to the team that lies in another office for the same project, and see if it catches on. I'm hoping that with a good organic adoption roadmap and friendly and well-defined documentation for workflows will help avert this

Answer (score 7):

If your CVCS is slowing you down (would be he corollary from your question) then your workflow is broken not your VCS.

**Edit:**  (text to long for comment)

I think you are missing the point. If your procedures regarding VCS's can slow you down only if they make up a significant amount of your development time. This would be true if either the VCS or your process requires a huge amount of ceremony. I have never used perforce so I don't know how "bad" its ceremony is. I have used MKS and found its ceremony really bad, but it would still only account for a couple of minutes per day. With git my ceremony is maybe a couple of seconds a day. So my gain is less pain, but not much more speed, because if my day is 8h long it does not really matter if I save 10 minutes.

**BUT**: The pain is much (very much) smaller than with MKS and git makes things possible I could not do before. That is the *real* gain of DVCS.

Comment: Agree.  In an ideal world everybody could code at full speed and not worry about version control.  Hence the question is how far from an idea world the OP is.

Comment: But, conversely, wouldn't a DVCS that allows better workflows help increase speed?

Comment: DVCS's are not magic bullets or pixie dust.  If you have social or political problems, no amount of technical solutions will help.

Comment: @EricSchaefer: *"If your 486 DX with 256 MB of RAM is slowing you down, then your workflow is broken, not your workstation"*.

Comment: Can't really agree. We were in a situation where our (C)VCS system's lack of useable branching and merging was causing severe bottlenecks when we were trying to stabilise code for a release (while trying not to just tell all the coders to "stop checking in code"). I'm not sure any amount of clever workflow could have given us the ability to separate "stabilising" from "continued development" that switching to Mercurial gave us.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I'm not saying that, but technical solutions can indeed solve social or political problems. Remember **forking** a project used to have a bad connotation for open source projects?, see what happened after github (a technical solution) http://eaves.ca/2011/06/14/how-github-saved-opensource/

Comment: @HappyCat You could of just said SVN and left it at that. :)

Comment: @dukeofgaming a fork as seen on github has _nothing_ to do with the traditional sense of forking an open source project.  For examples see "XEmacs/GNU Emacs" or "LibreOffice/OpenOffice".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen That is my point exactly. Forking used to be regarded as something negative for OSS and IMHO almost a synonym of community fragmentation. Now it doesn't, and its not exclusive of github anymore. Forking a repository in a DVCS it is a way of dissemination, not fragmentation (like in a CVCS), because there is a way of still being connected to the original repo and getting contributions back. I know what forking means, and it's general connotation has certainly evolved thanks to these projects.

Comment: @dukeofgaming Forking has two different meanings, depending on the context.  In the case of github, you're forking a repository, but not necessarily the project itself.  Forking an open source project means that you will end up renaming it, creating a separate master source repository, and managing it as a project with loose ties to the original.  Forking jQuery on github just to have a place to do my own patches and submit pull requests is very different from forking jQuery on github, renaming it to jUberScript, and pushing it as a new project.  Fork...one word, multiple meanings.

Comment: So to you a DVCS and a CVS are equally good? You can't say that switching to a DVCS wouldn't increase development speed and at the same time that DVCSs are better (because in the end better comes down to development speed).

Comment: @EricSchaefer Do you exchange changes with peers before getting them into the blessed (or "central") repository?

Comment: @dukeofgaming With MKS never, with git rarely.

Comment: @Andrew Finnell - wasn't actually SVN - http://www.teamcoherence.com/versioncontrol.aspx - not too bad when the team was 4-5 people, but didn't scale at all well.  Shame as the dev actually works for us (which is why we adopted it in the first place)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In day to day coding, there is not much of a difference time-wise whether you use one or other source control.

As for the learning curve of a new methodology in a group: the larger the group the steeper the curve.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on your development processes, build process, release management, and branch management.  You need to pick the best VCS to support these without worrying about if it's centralized or distributed.  The VCS should support your processes and you should not have to mold your processes to the VCS (within reason).